# How to resolve Onedrive API Access Denied error?

Tags: java, onedrive

I'm integrating onedrive to my application to get files in users onedrive. I created an application in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList.
Following is the url to get the sign in window and get user authentication.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={clientID}&scope=Files.ReadWrite.All offline_access&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/onedrive/code
```

The onedrive passes the code and I'm capturing that and using the following request I can get the access_token and refresh_token too.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/onedrive/code&client_secret={client_secret}&code={code}&grant_type=authorization_code
```

Then I store the refresh token in my DB.

Later,
When I want to get files in users onedrive, I send my refresh+token and get an access_toke like the following.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id=client_id}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/onedrive/code&client_secret={client_secret}&&refresh_token=&refresh_token_stored_in_db}&grant_type=refresh_token
```

I get the access token from the above and use it to get the list of files in user onedrive like following. (Is this the correct API to call?)

```
GET https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root/children

Authorization: bearer {access_token}
```

**The problem is in this process. The response is,**

**{"error":{"code":"unauthenticated","message":"Authentication failed"}}**

Can someone please tell me what is the problem in my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got the same problem with node.js :D also no comment on my post :/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451819/how-to-onedrive-api-file-uploads-with-node-js