# How to get MIME type of the uploaded file in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

While implementing file upload using Microsoft Graph API I faced the issue that once I upload file I don't get MIME type of it. I can't send it via API as well as it's not determined automatically. I use resumable upload API:

https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_large_files.htm

I was thinking about determining it from the name(extension part) on my side, when I get the name of the file, but I hope there is a better way to do this with OneDrive Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: Are you making calls to business accounts via MS Graph?

Comment: Can I ask you about the mimeType and file size of file you uploaded?

Comment: @Brad I'm afraid we haven't bought that yet.

Comment: @Tanaike for now it's mp4 file that has size over 30 MB

Comment: I tried to upload mp4 with over 30MB. I confirmed that in my environment, mp4 movie with the size of 50MB could be uploaded and the mimeType of ``video/mp4`` was automatically given. The sample script I used is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45684079/onedrive-api-node-js-can%C2%B4t-use-createuploadsession-content-range-error/45684427#45684427 I hope this information will be helpful for you.

Comment: There is a difference between Business and Consumer on this front which is why I was looking for some clarification - see https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/643 for some details

Comment: @Tanaike where did you find the mime type? 
https://dev.onedrive.com/resources/item.htm resource just doesn't have it

Comment: In file facet I have something like this: 
  "file": {
    "hashes": {
      "quickXorHash": "nzVCFwCojs+ZfdrTaYAedROm1QY="
    }
  },

Comment: There is no parameter for including mimeType. By uploading the file, the mimeType was given automatically. My account is not for Business.

Comment: File section has a mime type in your case or you get it somewhere else ?

Comment: When it completed the upload of the file, ``mimeType`` is included in the response. Also I use the resumable upload method. When I uploaded a zip file with the filename of "sample.png", ``mimeType`` of the uploaded response was ``image/png``. So it is found that OneDrive defines ``mimeType`` by the extension of the file. In this case, ``the resumable upload`` is used. For example, when you use [the simple upload](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_put.htm), how will mimeType be? And if you reply me, can you add ``@Tanaike``? When ``@Tanaike`` is not added, I cannot notice to your reply.