# Can't access one drive through graph API using Azure app

Tags: node.js, azure, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am referring [this medium blog](https://medium.com/@fiqriismail/how-to-get-an-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-api-using-node-js-258723f29cc6) and [the official document from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) to access one drive through graph API using the Azure app. I am using the following node.js code to get access token for Microsoft Graph API:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const qs = require('qs');

const postData = {
 client_id: client_id from azure app,
 scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
 client_secret: app_secret from azure app
 grant_type: 'client_credentials'
};

axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

try{
  let res = await axios.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant from azure app}/oauth2/v2.0/token', qs.stringify(postData));
  console.log(res.data);
}catch (e) {
   console.log(e.message);
}
```

The above code returns the following response:

```
{
token_type: 'Bearer',
expires_in: 3599,
ext_expires_in: 3599,
access_token: 'value of access token'
}
```

Everything works fine till the above step. I take the access token from the above response and try to execute the following graph API to access one drive:

```
 let config = { headers:
     {'Authorization': "Bearer "+ res.data.access_token}  # Obtain access token from the above response
 };
 let res_drive = await axios.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe", config);
```

However, the above graph API call returns the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-07-02T14:08:36",
      "request-id": "67ef24fa-XXXX-XXXX-853a-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
  }
}
```

I have also set the permission to access graph API using Azure application as shown below:
[image]

Please let me know in case I am missing something.

How can I access one drive through graph API using the Azure app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way how token is acquired in your example corresponds to [*OAuth client credentials grant flow*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) (*application permissions*). There is no `me` context available in this flow (it just an alias for *the signed-in user*) since there is *no presence of signed-in user* in this flow and that's the reason why the provided error occurs in the first place.

To call `shared files` endpoint in this flow, user needs to be [explicitly provided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/drive/sharedWithMe
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Do you have any idea how can I access one drive folder shared with my organization? I tried ```https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/drive/sharedWithMe```  but I can't find that folder. Any hint please?

Comment: Not sure, `sharedWithMe` endpoint should return folder facets along with files. Are you positive it is not getting returned, maybe your query returns several pages?  Would suggest to raise another question and provide some details?

Comment: Using ```sharedWithMe``` endpoint, I can see shared files but these files are within my organization. I can't' see any file in this endpoint outside of my organization. I also found an issue on GitHub related to this https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2581.